# writing and reading a row mysql DB

Tags: mysql

On an online application, if I write a row into a mysql database and try to read the same row trying to get the information I tried to save before, what should I do to be sure this will happen? How can I do to avoid someone else using the same row?

Thanks

Comment: errrr... um... see if it exists first, in a WHERE clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this problem the [mysql transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html) are used. So, for example when you open the transaction the database state "freezes" so that we would perform the **INSERT** and then we would do the **READ**, and the changes would not be confirmed in the DB until doing **COMMIT**. If there have been exceptions along the way we will make ROLLBACK to return to the initial state.

The transactions assure us that between transaction opening and closing we are dealing with a unique database state for us.